# WebView and MenuItem

Tags: android, webview, menuitem

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    menu.add("Bar Graph");
    menu.add("Linear Graph");
    return true;
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(item.getTitle().equals("Bar Graph"))
    {
           myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById(\"Bar\").style.display = 'block';");
        myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById(\"Linear\").style.display = 'none';");

        return true;
    }
    else if(item.getTitle().equals("Linear Graph"))
    {
        myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById(\"Bar\").style.display = 'none';");
        myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById(\"Linear\").style.display ='block';");

        return true;
    }

     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://localhost:8080/index.html");

}
```

> There are two graphs in my website - Bar and Linear. I want to display/hide the graphs on click of menu item.

The above code is suppose to show and hide the two charts on click of their respective titles, but it works only once. If I click on "Bar Graph", the bar graph does get displayed and linear Graph is hidden which is fine. But if I click on "Chart Graph" the bar graph is still displayed and linear graph is still hidden. Also, if I click on Linear Graph FIRST then only linear graph is displayed(which is fine) but on click of bar graph no change is made. Basically, the action for the menu Item clicked first is permanent.

Please help!

Comment: what u want exactly buddy?

Comment: [Stacks28](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1508671/stacks28)- Please let me know the part which you did not get.

Comment: is ur bar static or dynamic ? and u just wanna show and hide ? or add some value and again show new one?

Comment: [Stacks28](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1508671/stacks28) The graphs are dynamic. I just want to show and hide the graphs using Javascript.